SMTShowMesh with additional graphics in SMTRestart session
Some time ago I posted a question concerning additional graphics for SMTShowMesh[]
SMTShowMesh with additional graphics
Now I want to include additional graphics in SMTRestart[] session for SMTShowMesh[] generated at each calculated time step using the same approach as in the link above but it doesn't work.
The example code is below
<< AceFEM`;
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["Domain1", "OL:SED3H1DFHYH1NeoHooke", {}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{"X" == 0 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{"X" == 1 &, 1 -> 1}];
SMTMesh["Domain1", 
  "H1", {5, 5, 
   5}, {{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 
      1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}}];
SMTAnalysis["Output" -> "Log.txt", "DumpInputTo" -> "File1"];
Clear[\[Lambda]]; \[Lambda][t_] := t;
SMTNextStep[0.01, \[Lambda]];
While[
  While[step = 
    SMTConvergence[10^-8, 10, {"Adaptive Time", 8, 0.001, 0.01, 1}],
    SMTNewtonIteration[];];
  If[Not[step[[1]]],
   force = (Plus @@ SMTResidual["X" == 0 (*&& "ID"\[Equal]"D"*)&])[[
     1]];
   SMTPut[SMTRData["Multiplier"], force];];
  If[step[[4]] === "MinBound", 
   Print["Error: \[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda] < \
\[CapitalDelta]\[Lambda]min"];];
  step[[3]] 
  , If[step[[1]], SMTStepBack[];];
  SMTNextStep[step[[2]], \[Lambda]]
  ];

<< AceFEM`;
SMTRestart["File1"];
{allkeys, allpost} = SMTGet[];
ListLinePlot[
 Map[(force = SMTGet[#][[1]]; {SMTRData["Multiplier"], -force}) &, 
  allkeys]]
(*SMSTShowMesh for the last step + additional graphics*)
SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]
Show[SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}], 
 Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0.5, 0.5, 1}]}}]]
(*SMSTShowMesh for the first step*)
Map[(SMTGet[#];
    SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", 
     "Show" -> True, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
     ImageSize -> 300];
    ) &, {allkeys[[1]]}];
(*SMSTShowMesh for the first step + additional graphics - does not work*)
Show[Map[(SMTGet[#];
    SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", 
     "Show" -> True, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
     ImageSize -> 300];
    ) &, {allkeys[[1]]}], 
Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0.5, 0.5, 1}]}}]]

I see that the output from Map[(SMTGet...] is {Null} but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

You did two errors.

The "Show"->True option creates a new notebook cell, but it does not return the graphics. "Show"->False is correct in your case. See manual:


2)You have ended the statement with ; which in MMA results in Null.

I have changed "Show"-> False, and added semicolon: Show[Map[(SMTGet[#];
SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx",
"Show" -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity},
ImageSize -> 300];
) &, {allkeys[[1]]}];,
Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0.5, 0.5, 1}]}}]] but still the output is Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[Null,].

You have to remove the semicolons. It is the way how the Mathematica works. If any statement ends with ";", the result of particular statement is Null.
